# Updating magento 2.0.x error - always_populate_raw_post_data and other errors

Tags: magento, installation, updates

So while updating magento I get the following error:

```
.setup_cronjob_status

{
    "readiness_checks": {
        "db_write_permission_verified": true
    },
    "php_checks": {
        "php_version_verified": {
            "responseType": "error",
            "data": {
                "error": "phpVersionError",
                "message": "Cannot determine required PHP version: Cannot find php version requirement in 'composer.lock' file"
            }
        },
        "php_extensions_verified": {
            "responseType": "success",
            "data": {
                "required": [],
                "missing": []
            }
        },
        "php_settings_verified": {
            "responseType": "success",
            "data": {
                "always_populate_raw_post_data": {
                    "message": "Your PHP Version is 5.5.32, but always_populate_raw_post_data = -1.\n \t        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0.\n \t        This will stop the installer from running.\n\t        Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1.\n \t        If you need more help please call your hosting provider.",
                    "helpUrl": "http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-settings-data",
                    "error": false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "last_timestamp": 1462759382,
    "current_timestamp": 1462759625
}
```

What is the real error? 
The phpVersionError ? 
Or always_populate_raw_post_data ? 
Because as the error says, I already set it to -1.

And if it's phpVersionError, how do I resolve it? 
I tried composer update on magento and it broke my installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to uncomment always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 in php.ini file If you are using version  from Magento 2.0.1 to 2.0.6 but magento 2.0.7 doesn't support php 5.5 So, better way is to use php 5.6 for magento 2.0.x